# Integration of Microsoft Exchange server with Drupal

Tags: authentication-authorization

I am using Drupal 7.

I would like to integrate Microsoft Exchange server with my Drupal site, so that I can login with the credentials of Exchange server and can also integrate with other features of Exchange server like Events, Calenders etc.

I checked one module called [LDAP(Light Weight Directory Access Protocol)](http://drupal.org/project/ldap), and it is working with other servers, But i don't know whether I can use this integration with Microsoft Exchange server.

Answer (score 1):

All recent version of Exchange (2000+) require and Active directory for the authentication and authorization.  Active Directory is integrated via LDAP.